# Swift pass in struct as function parameter

Tags: swift

I have a JSON parsing class like so

```
class JSONParser: NSObject {
    let newJSONDecoder : JSONDecoder
    let data : Data

    init(decoder: JSONDecoder, data: Data, model:  ) {
        self.newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

The goal is to have the `model` parameter be a class that can take in any data and any model and create an object and return it to the calling class instance. EG below

```
let jsonParser = JSONParser(myDecoder, data, struct)
let parsedArray = jsonParser.createJSONArray()
```

Can I pass in a struct to the JSONParser init method of type `struct` and not of type struct "class" name (eg ModelStruct)?

Eventually, the struct parameter should get used in this function

`try newJSONDecoder.decode(model.self, from:data!)`, so the second issue is how to get it into that function - won't work if printed as a String.

Comment: Do you want to pass specific struct or generic?

Comment: generic struct - basically to parse JSON since I did not use a class. Goal is to make dependencies know in initialization.

Comment: Why can't you just use `JSONDecoder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
class JSONParser: NSObject {
    let newJSONDecoder : JSONDecoder
    let data : Data

    init<T: Codable>(data: Data, model: T.Type) {
        self.newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
        let result = try self.newJSONDecoder.decode(model.self, from: data)
        print(result)
        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Your model struct:

```
struct TestModel: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

How you call init:

```
let str = """
        {"name": "Robert", "age" : 35}
        """

    let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
    let jsonParser = JSONParser(data: data!, model: TestModel.self)
```

Comment: I think this will work. Could you add an explanation for `<T: Codable>` part of the code?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs `<T: Codable>` define type of `model`. Here model must be type of Codable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I pass generic Codable struct as a parameter and also return it via completion handler as parameter, allGeneric :

```
func getAccordingToWebServiceFlag<T:Decodable>(flagSender: WebServicesFlagSenders,codableStruct: T.Type ,completionHandler: @escaping ( _ publicDataResponseModel:T?,_ flagSender: WebServicesFlagSenders) -> Void) {

excuteServerOperation(nil, imageData: nil, url:ServerAPIServant.webServiceFullURL(webServicesFlagSenders: flagSender), way: .get, flagSender: flagSender,completionHandler: { (result, flagSender) in
    AppDelegate().printStringBy_ispha(string: "  \(flagSender) Hmmm  \(result)")
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:  result , options: .prettyPrinted)
        let decodableResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(codableStruct, from: jsonData)

        HelpingMethods.printCustomObjectBy_ispha(anyObject: decodableResponse as AnyObject)
        completionHandler(decodableResponse,flagSender)
    } catch let error {
        HelpingMethods.printStringBy_ispha(string: " Codable failure with error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
         completionHandler(nil,flagSender)
    }


}
)}
```